# Which would be more applicable lmx or cc2564?

Tags: bluetooth, texas-instruments

I'm looking for the difference's between a LMX family ic vs a CC256x family from TI and what you think would best fit my application. First my application is quite simple I'm using bluetooth to be able to write to the mcu EEPROM,and data log while the mcu is running.All transmitting over a UART connection.

The first major difference I can notice is the LMX requires less components for it to operate vs the CC256x. But that comes with a more pricey tag to it. Is this the only difference the LMX is a easier plug and play compared to the CC256x?Now im not limited to just these two products these were the two I felt would satisfy my application requirements.Any input is appreciated thanks

UPDATE:well typically once I post a question i find the answer. So the lmx has less components,and also has the bluetooth stack and profiles embedded in.While the cc256x family requires the mcu to contain the bluetooth stack and profiles.

So im going a complete opposite direction going to use the Toshiba TC35661SBG-203 has the stack and profiles embedded and the price is half compared to the lmx and will support my MCU without have to use one of TI ARM Cotex.Hope it helps someone